# Прикрутить HTTPS в проект использующий Jetty

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

Задача: написать небольшой веб-сервис, к которому с заданной частотой будет обращаться сторонний клиент по https для получения данных.

При выборе интрумента было решено использовать jetty (показался интересной библиотекой) ну и, соответственно, Java.

Сгенирировал через openssl самоподписанный сертификат, rsa:2048.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прицепить мой сертификат к приложению. (Прицепить именно из кода).

Comment: А вы здесь искали?  https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL

Answer (score 0):

Примерно что то типа того, закомментированный текст - добавление сертификата в хранилище

```
package com.example;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class Main {
/*
  private static InputStream fullStream(String fname) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fname);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[dis.available()];
    dis.readFully(bytes);
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    return bais;
  }
*/
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
/*
  String certfile = "yourcert.cer";
  FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream("yourKeyStore.keystore");
  KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
  keystore.load(is, "yourKeyStorePass".toCharArray());
  String alias = "youralias";
  char[] password = "yourKeyStorePass".toCharArray();
  CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
  InputStream certstream = fullStream (certfile);
  Certificate certs =  cf.generateCertificate(certstream);
  File keystoreFile = new File("yourKeyStorePass.keystore");
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile);
  keystore.load(in, password);
  in.close();
  keystore.setCertificateEntry(alias, certs);
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(keystoreFile);
  keystore.store(out, password);
  out.close();
*/
        Server server = new Server();
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");
        server.setHandler(webapp);
        HttpConfiguration http = new HttpConfiguration();
        http.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
        http.setSecurePort(8443);
        http.setSecureScheme("https");
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.addConnectionFactory(new HttpConnectionFactory(http));
        connector.setPort(8080);
        HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
        https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(
            Main.class.getResource("keystore").toExternalForm()
        );
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("javacodegeeks");
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("javacodegeeks");
        ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(
            server, 
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"), 
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https)
        );
        sslConnector.setPort(8443);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector, sslConnector});
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```